# Generating Spring REST webservice using MyEclipse

Tags: java, spring, rest, web-services, myeclipse

I am using MyEclipse to generate a CRUD Application with REST service , the web CRUD application is well generated and working fine , but i want use also the REST service , the RestControler generated is like that :

```
@Controller("NewsRestController")

public class NewsRestController {

    /**
     * DAO injected by Spring that manages News entities
     * 
     */
    @Autowired
    private NewsDAO newsDAO;

    /**
     * Service injected by Spring that provides CRUD operations for News entities
     * 
     */
    @Autowired
    private NewsService newsService;

    /**
     * Create a new News entity
     * 
     */
    @RequestMapping(value = "/News", method = RequestMethod.POST)
    @ResponseBody
    public News newNews(@RequestBody News news) {
        newsService.saveNews(news);
        return newsDAO.findNewsByPrimaryKey(news.getId());
    }

    /**
    * Show all News entities
    * 
    */
    @RequestMapping(value = "/News", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    @ResponseBody
    public List<News> listNewss() {
        return new java.util.ArrayList<News>(newsService.loadNewss());
    }
```

i tried to call this service using this url :

```
http://localhost:8080/JPO/NewsRestController/News
```

i use Postman to test this REST service , i could not get any response.
what can be the problem ?

Comment: i tried it but not working

Comment: Try `http://localhost:8080/JPO//News` in postman, select `Get` method, and you'd better declare a new path for the get mapping.

Comment: i get a HTTP 406 error , it's something to do with Accept headers

Comment: i had to add jackson jars , now it's working , thx for your help guys

Answer (score 0):

The parameter to `@Controller` annotation is to define a bean of given name `NewsRestController` to be used in spring context autowiring, its not to create a dispatcher URI mapping. You should be using `@RequestMapping` annotation like below to create URI path to be controlled by given controller.

```
@Controller("NewsRestController")
@RequestMapping("/NewsRestController")
```

Update: To your Http 406 error, make sure you have jackson jars in your classpath for json conversion.

Answer (score 0):

Using the port 8080 and the next implementation

```
@SpringBootApplication
@ComponentScan
@RestController
public class ApplicationStarter {

    @RequestMapping(value = "/News", method = RequestMethod.GET, produces="application/json")    
    public ResponseEntity<String> newNews() {

        return ResponseEntity.ok("{  \"message\" : \"Testing Rest services!!!\" }");
    }

    @RequestMapping
    public static void main(String[] args) {

        SpringApplication.run(ApplicationStarter.class, args);
    }
}
```

You must consume the service using:

```
http://localhost:8080/News
```

To get the below response:

```
{  "message" : "Testing Rest services!!!" }
```

When you run your application take a look at the log, it must say to you the path you need to consume, just add localhost:8080 at the beginning, below you can find my log for this example

```
2018-06-07 23:00:37.030  INFO 15552 --- [           main] s.w.s.m.m.a.RequestMappingHandlerMapping : Mapped "{[/News],methods=[GET],produces=[application/json]}" onto public org.springframework.http.ResponseEntity<java.lang.String> org.tocode.hystrix.ApplicationStarter.newNews()
2018-06-07 23:00:37.034  INFO 15552 --- [           main] s.w.s.m.m.a.RequestMappingHandlerMapping : Mapped "{[/messages],methods=[GET],produces=[application/json]}" onto public org.springframework.http.ResponseEntity<java.util.List<java.lang.String>> org.tocode.hystrix.controller.HystrixController.getMessages()
2018-06-07 23:00:37.036  INFO 15552 --- [           main] s.w.s.m.m.a.RequestMappingHandlerMapping : Mapped "{[/uniq-messages/],methods=[GET]}" onto public org.springframework.http.ResponseEntity<java.lang.String> org.tocode.hystrix.controller.HystrixController.getUniqMessage()
2018-06-07 23:00:37.137  INFO 15552 --- [           main] s.w.s.m.m.a.RequestMappingHandlerMapping : Mapped "{[/messages/{messageId}],methods=[GET],produces=[application/json]}" onto public org.springframework.http.ResponseEntity<java.lang.String> org.tocode.hystrix.controller.HystrixController.getMessageById(int)
2018-06-07 23:00:37.140  INFO 15552 --- [           main] s.w.s.m.m.a.RequestMappingHandlerMapping : Mapped "{[/myapp/user/{id}],methods=[GET]}" onto public org.springframework.http.ResponseEntity<java.lang.String> org.tocode.hystrix.controller.User.getId(int)
```

Comment: I am not using spring boot, i use a spring mvc app

Comment: Springboot just avoid configuration tasks but it is almost the same, take a look at the logs when you run your application, on another hand try a @RestController instead